# PHP array with variables inside?

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

I need help :)

I have a while/loop that gets values from my database. This loop combines database values with `$_POST` input and generales a `$score` for each item.
CODE:

---

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
    $score=($row["near_beach_score"]*$result_a)+
    ($row["near_city_score"]*result_b)+
    ($row["near_swim_pool_score"]*result_c)+
    ($row["near_public_transport_score"]*result_d)+
    $row["house_promote_score"];

$array_content.='array('.$row["id"].', '.$score.') ';
```

---

when the while/loop is done I want to have a multiple array with the content of the string generated in the while/loop.

Like: `$complete_array = array ($array_content);`

and then i want to apply a `array_multisort`.

How to concatenate/insert `$array_content` into `$complete_array = array ($array_content);` ?

Apreciate if you have time to help.
/Sérgio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is a unique field:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $score = ...;
    $arr[$row['id']] = $score;
}
```

It stores the value of `$row['id']` in the keys and `$score` in the values.

Comment: Thank you Jack! I did as you suggested and did arsort($arr); to sort my array. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array_content = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $score=($row["near_beach_score"]*$result_a) + 
            ($row["near_city_score"]*result_b)+ 
            ($row["near_swim_pool_score"]*result_c)+ 
            ($row["near_public_transport_score"]*result_d)+ 
            $row["house_promote_score"];

    $array_content []=array($row["id"], $score);
}
```

you produced a `String`. If you remove the `'` you will get an `array`